# Bad use of position:relative in CSS, advice needed

Tags: css, position, containers, styling, css-position

[image: http://imgur.com/ZzkxK] ...Screenshot of my abomination

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ELZD8/

It was looking fine, until I needed to change the fieldset size: and since I was using position:relative for literally every element on the page, changing the fieldset screwed everything up, bad. Forgive me but I'm pretty new to CSS and I know I'm using wayyy too much code.

So, as you can see in the imgur, it looks like hell now. What's the quickest way to fix this? I know it probably has to do with floats and margin:left and margin: right, but could someone provide some insight before I go bananas?

Any input is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: I don't think there *is* a particularly quick way to fix it if you're using `position: relative; top: ?px; left: ?px` for everything.

Comment: @thirtydot, that's what I've been doing. position:relative, and a top and left value. But that CAN'T be ideal? Right?

Comment: Just one thought, apart from your question: why are you styling every label and input element apart? Why not .input{ some common CSS here, like background;} . Would make this much clearer.

Comment: Well that's the thing, I know that's not ideal but given that the form lengths are different in certain areas of the page and the height of labels differs alot, don't I need to make every element by itself? Sorry for the noob questions.

Comment: 'Worst way possible', lol, I figured :( Guess at this point I'll just manually readjust top and left? Ugh, fml. For future reference though, how would you go about this?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. See http://jsfiddle.net/JE59W/. And yes, I would also suggest to start from the scratch again. Google for some nice tutorials.

Comment: Ok, for sure. Appreciate it guys/gals.

Comment: Alright well I started from scratch, definitely going better but not sure I'm still ideal: @Dennis Hunink, I see what you're saying about the .input {common css etc etc}, but I'm still going to have certain elements on their own right? I mean how else would I align/position them properly? Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: Just a tip, along with what @DennisHunink said about using common css for elements, you should also consider using containers. Its NEVER a good idea to have to position every single element especially if they are all relative to the same position. I would of split your page into 3 different containers at least. Then if something's size had to be changed only the things inside of the same container need to be re-positioned/re-sized. Since the rest of the elements are positioned relative to their container and not the whole page.

Comment: Thanks for the input Ryan. Stuck once again here though. I'm really not trying to use position:relative/absolute/fixed and now the margin thing won't even change the position. I'm trying to move an element upwards, and when I do (ie margin: -90px 0px 10px 220px;) it only recognizes the 220px and moves it left. What the hell is up with that?

Comment: Margin applies to elements in different ways depending on what their parent element is and what level of element they are. If they are block level and inside of another block level element then for margin to apply properly they both have to have a set width and height. If the parent element does not have a height or the element you are trying to position does not have a height then how is the margin supposed to know where to put the element in relation to the other, since it doesn't know the size of either.

Comment: Could you give us a updated jsfiddle? I'm wondering what you've got right now, and maybe help you to not make certain obvious mistakes again..

Comment: My buddy helped me out, gimmie a few here and I'll post it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mvFM4/. It runs fine in Chrome but within fiddle it looks kinda off down low. Anyways, not perfect but much cleaner. As my friend said we did it "dirty" because of all the clears. Thoughts? I appreciate you following up @Dennis Hunink :)

Comment: No problem; the only way to learn is by getting help from others. Couple of things about your fiddle. First of all, it looks much better. Second: you don't need to set a class like .textInput. You can apply CSS like input{}. Don't declare font-famliy every time; no need for that. Same for color. You can declare css for input types, like input[type=checkbox]. I made some small changes to http://jsfiddle.net/mvFM4/1/ to illustrate. Hope it helps. Feel free to ask for heads up again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix:

You need to use proper div sectioning, that is, make each section a div and then place elements inside each div, otherwise it becomes a clusterfuck. You also need to list your elements in your css file by order of appearance in the html, otherwise it's painful to look for things...

Don't use massive amounts of `<br>`, use padding and margin css rules instead

Yes, you may use position:relative, but since you asked for advice, I am strongly against it, it takes longer to build, longer to update, longer to fix, etc. Use sections, floats and keep it simple, Simple is your friend.

I also suggest strongly against using `fieldset`, use `<form>` instead, its a major html/css breaker imo.

Here's a chopped up example after cleaning/tweaking the code considerably. There's still a thousand ways left to clean and refine it but at least now it looks more like what I suppose you wanted:

http://sotkra.com/stackoverflow/positionrelative/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the response Sotkra, and I appreciate you rewriting it! My one drupal buddy also said you shouldn't have to use much more than floats and margins. Looking forward to your response :)

Comment: should be done tomorrow, haven't been home much these last few days

Comment: ok, sorry about the delay, let me upload the code and i'll edit this comment when its set

Comment: it is important to note that i didn't pile up some input fields into the same row but, it's just a matter of putting them inside divs and giving these divs their proper float:left; and width:px or % rules accordingly